# Mouse Quits Working in Linux After Login

Tags: linux, mouse

I am having problems with my (USB) mouse!  I'm reinstalling my computer, and every time I get started up, I can move my mouse for about 10 seconds from when I start moving it, then it won't move, won't click, etc.  I've now tried Kubuntu 13.04, Mint 15, and Arch, and all have the same problem.  Plugging in another mouse works fine.

It's not the mouse itself, as it worked in Windows 8 on the same computer just earlier today.  Additionally, it works without a problem when plugged into my MacBook.  It's not the port, I've tried several ports on the same computer.

dmesg, lspci, lsusb, etc. show no relevant information, only that they detect the mouse.  I can find no log event when the mouse quits working.

The only thing that's changed, and I don't see how it would be relevant at all, is I replaced an internal hd with an ssd.

For the record, it's a Razer Tron mouse.

Comment: Does it work with older versions, e.g. 12.10?  Try especially an LTS release, which I think the last one was 12.04.  There might be a regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a defective mouse.  It had an identity crisis and also thought it was a keyboard.  I guess Windows and OS X were less picky than Linux.  I sent it off for an RMA and they're replacing it.